# Java bit shifting and colours

Tags: java, bit-shift

hi i'm quite new at java and i am having a problem where my colors were monochromatic so i changed something and then now all i have is a black screen these are my graphics classes

```
    package game.game.gfx;

public class Screen 
{
public static final int MAP_WIDTH =64;
public static final int MAP_WIDTH_MASK = MAP_WIDTH -1;

public int[]pixels;

public int xOffset =0;
public int yOffset =0;
public int width;
public int height;

public SpriteSheet sheet;
public Screen(int width,int height,SpriteSheet sheet)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.sheet = sheet;

    pixels = new int[width*height];
    }


public  void render(int xPos,int yPos,int tile,int colour){
    xPos -=xOffset;
    yPos -=yOffset;
    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int tileOffset = (xTile<<3)+(yTile<<3)*sheet.width;
    for(int y=0;y<8;y++){
        if(y+yPos < 0 || y + yPos >=height) continue;
        int ySheet=y;

        for(int x=0;x<8;x++){
            if(x+xPos <0||x+xPos >=width) continue;
            int xSheet=x;
            int col = (colour >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet*sheet.width+tileOffset]*8))& 255;
            if(col<255)pixels[(x+xPos)+(y+yPos)*width]=col;
        }
    }

}

}
```

========

## SpriteSheet

```
    package game.game.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class SpriteSheet 
{
public String path;
public int width;
public int height;

public int[]pixels;
public SpriteSheet(String path)
{
BufferedImage image = null; 

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (image == null)
{
    return;
}
this.path = path;
this.width = image.getWidth();
this.height = image.getHeight();

pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
for (int i =0; i < pixels.length;i++)
{
    pixels[i] =(pixels[i]&0xff)/64;
}
for (int i =0;i<8;i++)
{
System.out.println(pixels[i]);  
}

}
}
```

=====

## colours

```
package game.game.gfx;

public class Colours {
public static int get(int colour1,int colour2,int colour3,int colour4){
    return  (get(colour4)<<24)+(get(colour3)<<16+(get(colour2)<<8)+get(colour1));   
}
private static int get(int colour) {
    if(colour < 0)return 255;
    int r =colour/ 100 % 10;
    int g =colour/ 10 % 10;
    int b =colour % 10;
    return r*36+g*6+b;
}
}
```

Comment: Use `java.nio.ByteBuffer` instead of shifting, this class split an int value(pixel/color) into the a 4-length byte array (argb), [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc) would help you dude :)

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure how i would convert it easily any help?

Comment: like this `byte[] color=ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(<<int color value>>).array()` and for doing vice versa use the wrap() method like `int color32bit=ByteBuffer.wrap(<<byte array>>).getInt()`

Comment: i don't understand at all sorry so do i just replace it with that or change multiple things if its not to big a ask could you replace it as i am clueless

Comment: which algorithm did you use for making your image monochromatic? the result of black image is may because of wrong number of alpha value. also I think the funtionallity of the Colours class is not correct, I think the private get method should return byte, and you should return a 4-len byte as int from the first get method, nor adding them with each other.